# Highlight the bucket that contains the current time

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have created a timeline that is divided into 10 minute buckets, and I want to highlight the current bucket that contains the current time:

[image]

The formula that has helped me so far is highlighting all the passed times represented on the following formula:

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))>P4,TRUE,FALSE)
```

But what about highlighting only the cell that contains the current time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AND():

(Note the IF is not needed):

```
=AND(TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))>P4,TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))<P4+TIME(0,10,0))
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! very long formula though. I hope it won't effect its function

Thanks,
Juwaiber